# issue convert double range number to binary

Tags: c

I have a problem to convert integer type's double rage number to binary as the below,

```
void intToBin(int digit) {
    int b;
    int k = 0;
    char *bits;
    int i;

    bits= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    while (digit) {
        b = digit % 2;
        digit = digit / 2;
        bits[k] = b;
        k++;
    }
    for ( i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", bits[i]);
    }
}
```

But as you can see the that function's arguments input is integer.

I came across the error when I tried with `intToBin(10329216702565230)`
because `10329216702565230` is  over integer range.

How can I extend what that have integer type's double rage number to binary ?

## update

I've updated the below code

```
void intToBin(uint64_t digit) {
    int b;
    int k = 0;
    char *bits;
    int i;
    
    bits = malloc(sizeof digit * 64);

    while (digit) {
        b = digit % 2;
        digit = digit / 2;
        bits[k] = b;
        k++;
    }
    for ( i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%d", bits[i]);
    }

}
```

But I didn't get it what should I do to get the 2's complement ?
m
dmnngn

Comment: O/T: `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates exactly one character's worth of memory, which is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: `bits= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));` --> `bits= malloc(sizeof digit * CHAR_BITS);`

Comment: Since you are not returning `bits`, there is no need to dynamically allocate anything. If you just want to print the binary representation to `stdout`, just pass `uint64_t digit`, set your `size_t size = sizeof digit * CHAR_BIT;` and then `while (size--) putchar ((digit >> size & 1) ? '1' : '0');` and you are done. (you can add `putchar ('\n');` at the end if you want to append a newline at the end, otherwise, handle that as needed in the caller). You add a check for `if (digit == 0)` at the beginning and just output zeros if it is and return.

Comment: If an `int` cannot represent the value `10329216702565230`, what to you expect to happen when you pass that value to a function expecting an `int`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is to use type which supports that range of numbers.

Use `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`(assuming you are passing non negative integers, otherwise use `long long` or `int64_t`). Then you call the function like this <sup>Edited to add `int64_t` to `uint64_t` from the comment posted. `unsigned long long` is 64 bits atleast - can even be wider. With OP's comment of getting 64 bits output - better to use `(u)int64_t`</sup>

`intToBin(10329216702565230U)`

In case you want to use negative numbers use `long long`.Call it like this
`intToBin(10329216702565230L)`.

You didn't allocate enough memory - you were accessing memory that you haven't allocated, resulting in [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You have allocated 1 `char` first and then you didn't allocate. You can solve this by reallocating  - reallocate memory inside the loop (reallocate `1` `char` at a time inside loop). And then use it. Instead of calling `realloc` multiple times why don't you allocate memory for `64` `char`s and then use it to store the result. And in the end, the left over space can be freed with another `realloc` call.

You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` (`void*` to `char*` conversion is done implicitly).
You didn't check the return value of `malloc`. `malloc` may return `NULL` and in that case you have to handle that separately. For example:-

```
   #define NBITS 64
   ...
   ...
   bits = malloc(NBITS);
   if( bits == NULL ){
       perror("malloc failed");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
```

Note: The 64 magic number is coming introduced with the thought that `unsigned long long` is `64` bits atleast. So while converting we will be using that in case the number of bits exceeds `64` we will reallocate. A better choice is to use what `chux` said - `sizeof digit * CHAR_BIT`.

Also

```
bits[k] = b+'0';
```

We are putting the ascii value and then you can print it like this

```
printf("%c", bits[i]);
```

You forgot to free the allocated memory. Without freeing it (`free(bits)`), you have memory leak.

<sub>Davic C. Rankins comment</sub>

Comment: `64` look like a [Magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: @chux.: Well I guess I shouldn't add without asking...but yes I considered that magic number thinking the logic you said...and if that is being reached it will have to reallocate

Comment: A good ole `#define NBITS 64` will get rid of the sorcery... `:)`

Comment: @coderredoc But I need to use negative number also like -10329216702565230

Comment: You can use `uint64_t`. The bits don't know if they are negative or not, that just an interpretation issue. (e.g. if it is a signed number and the bit at the left end is `1` -- it's a negative number in a twos-compliment system (which almost everything today is)). The only practical difference if `digit` is unsigned, is you eliminate sign-extension for smaller types. If you want to sign-extend (e.g. a `short`) to 64-bits, then use `int64_t` -- it's totally up to you.

Comment: @coderredoc  I'm not sure whether  because this or not, I came across "-10-1" instead "-1011" or "1011" when I excute the code. did I something missed?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Well if you pass a signed number to unsigned ..will it be right for conversion (Doubtful: OP wants signextended conversion?) ? I mean yes I get your point - the thing is the sign extended number will be the correct one but not sure if OP is looking for that

Comment: @start01.: What did you use as input? What do you expect?

Comment: I got `0000000000100100101100100101111000101100010111010100101101101110` as output using `10329216702565230` as input. (padded to 64-bits). You can eliminate the pad if you just want the binary starting with the MSB.

Comment: @coderredoc yes the input is singed 64bit integer. and I expected it to converted as a binary.  for example if I use -5 then the output can be expected to "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011"

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes I've got also it, Thanks but I'd like to use signed integer.

Comment: @start01.: tell me what will be input output for signed number? For signed I got this using unsigned number. `1111111111011011010011011010000111010011101000101011010010010010`

Comment: @start01, then simply use `int64_t digit` instead of `uint64_t` and you will *sign extend* `-5` to 64-bits.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: Or `long long`..any reason you avoiding `long long` mentioning?

Comment: None other than when you want exact width numbers, `stdint.h` is an unambiguous way to communicate that. `long long` should also be unambiguous for x86, but I simply cannot guarantee that for all hardware implementations. But, I can guarantee `int64_t` will be 64-bits, `int32_t` will be 32-bits, etc...

Comment: @coderredoc `long long` is _very_ commonly 64-bit.  It must be at least 64-bit.  Perhaps someday one may see a long long wider than 64-bit.  With an [expectation of 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236767/issue-convert-double-range-number-to-binary#comment83457014_48236775), then `(u)int64_t` is the best direct solution.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,  I implemented with int64_t, but it still  "-10-1" not I expected as "1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011" .

Comment: @chux.: Ah ye...OP's comment.

Comment: @chux Is commonly using long long rather than int64_t ? in wider than 64bit system?

Comment: @start01 I know of no platform using wider than 64-bit `long long`.  Give it 10 years.

Comment: @start01 Have a look at [Padded & Unpadded Binary Representation of Signed Number](https://pastebin.com/6h84yEBR) It will give you your original number and `0` through `-10`. (as an example) in the implementation I use. You can continue to use yours, it's just a bit more CPU intensive.

Comment: @chux Thanks, But the problem is that the result don't complement 2's How do add a 2's complement logic?

Comment: @start01 `void intToBin(int digit)` --> `void intToBin(uint64_t digit)`.  Call with `intToBin(-5);`.

Comment: @chux : thanks. I've got "-101" after call with intToBin(-5). but it's does not applied 2's complement.

Comment: @start01 Look/code [carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236767/issue-convert-double-range-number-to-binary/48236775?noredirect=1#comment83457327_48236775).

Comment: @chux  I already applied with "void intToBin(uint64_t digit)" as your recommend, did I miss?

Comment: @start01.: You are not following the answer...`bits[k]='0'+b`; and thnen print it with `%c`

Answer (score 1):

```
void intToBin(int digit)
{
int b;
int k = 0;
char *bits;
int i;

bits= (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
while (digit) {
    b = digit % 2;
    digit = digit / 2;
    bits[k] = b;
    k++;
}
for ( i = k - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", bits[i]);
}
}
```

The answer is simple,

***Replace int with int64_t to use 64 bits instead of 32.***
Please try it and let us know

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int` with `int64_t` to use 64 bits instead of 32.

Comment: Thanks, I missed introducing about I'll with also gcc & win64 environments

Comment: The `printf` is printing `bits[i]`, which has type `char`. Formatting it with `%ld` is not right. Nor is `%ld` right for `int64_t`.